# Can I attach a hyperlink to animated div without picking up ANY of hyperlink styles?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have made animated on hover divs but as soon as I attached hyperlinks to them purple outlines appeared. Codepen: https://codepen.io/forTheLoveOfCode/pen/yPEygM

The way I am attaching hyperlinks to divs at the moment is as follows:

```
  <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/misskatiapunter">
    <div class="communities-link" id="free-code-camp-butn">
      <i class="fa fa-free-code-camp ffc-text"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
```

What would be the best way to overwrite all hyperlink styles so that the only effect hyperlink has on a div is - to link it to another page.

Comment: Different browsers render hyperlinks differently. What browser are you seeing the purple outlines on? I don't appear to see them on either Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: I am using Chrome. If hyperlinks are commented out that is the look I am after. https://codepen.io/forTheLoveOfCode/pen/WXyxYV

Comment: Please include enough code to relicate the issue in the question itself, not a third party resource. Better still use SO Snippets, the `<>` button in the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is to set the **[`color` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color)** on the `a` tag, and you'll probably also want to set the **[`text-decoration` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)** to `none`:

```
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

`color: inherit` states that the element should inherit the colour from the parent element, if defined. If a parental colour is not defined, it will inherit a black colour from `<body>`.

`color: inherit` is the most commonly-desired usage, allowing you to *change* the colour, but if you need to override this for specific links you can use `color: initial`, which will set it back to its default value of blue:

```
a {
  color: inherit; /* Becomes black */
}
a.blue {
  color: initial; /* Becomes blue, overriding the inheritance from a */
}
```

`text-decoration: none` removes the underline from 'regular' hyperlinks. It won't have any effect in your specific use-case, but is useful if you want to remove the underline entirely.

I've created an updated pen showcasing this **[here](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/ooyLJE)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. However, attaching a div to hyperlink also interferes with justify-content: center. It is barely visible in my codepen but it is there. Any thoughts on how to overcome this? I think I should have put hyperlink inside the div.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not quite sure what you're talking about with regards to the interference, but maybe you could try `justify-content: space-between` or `justify-content: space-around`. Both `<a>` inside `<div>` and `<div>` inside `<a>` are perfectly valid under HTML 5, and considering both `<a>` and `<div>` are both [**flow content**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content), neither should interfere with the other.

Comment: I figured it out - hyperlinks are by default inline and should be inside block elements, placed the links inside dives to keep positioning. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever want to remove default styles, do it the same way that you would if you were to add the style. for instance: if the link has a purple outline, add a `a {border: 0;}` property, or if it appears whenever you hover it, do `a:hover{border: 0;}`, or if it shows when its clicked do `a:active{border: 0;}`